# Haskell Type constructors

Tags: haskell

Wanted to ask few questions regarding Haskell **Type Constructors**

Can some one provide me how type constructors work and some examples of it?

Also I need to know:

Are these type constructors?:

```
Numerical
Maybe
Show
[]
Eq
```

Thank you,

Julian

Comment: I would recommend checking out the Learn You A Haskell tutorial, which is one of the easiest to understand introductions to the language.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like homework you haven't tried to do yourself. You might find it enlightening to read [Learn You a Haskell on types and typeclasses](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type constructors are things which construct.. well types. Take `Maybe`, it takes one other type, let's say `a`, and returns a type `Maybe a` with two constructors

```
Just :: a -> Maybe a
Nothing :: Maybe a
```

We can talk about how many arguments a constructor takes with its "kind", a kind is the type of a type. Some examples,

```
Int :: *
Maybe :: * -> *
Either :: * -> * -> *
```

So a type constructor is a thing that takes some number of other types and returns a new type.

I'll leave the thing that looks like a homework question to you though.